# windows server 2008 r2 7z backup script

Tags: windows, batch-file, backup, 7zip

I am trying to get this script to backup a specific folder/files and zip them, then move the zip to a diff folder.

but i keep getting an error.

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL

ECHO + Setting up environment variables.
SET BACKPATH=%ThisService_RootDirectory%temp\
SET ARCPATH=C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe
SET ARCPARAMS=a -y
SET DAYSTOKEEP=3
SET ARCHIVE_DAYSTOKEEP=30
SET SOURCEPATH=%ThisService_RootDirectory%MPMissions
SET DEST_PATH=%ThisService_RootDirectory%Backups
SET BACKUP_DEST=%date:~-7,2%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~-4,4%

IF NOT EXIST "%BACKPATH%" (
ECHO ! Backup Path not found, exiting.
GOTO END
) ELSE (
ECHO * Backup Path Found.
)

IF NOT EXIST "%ARCPATH%" (
ECHO ! Archiver not found, exiting.
GOTO END
) ELSE (
ECHO * Archiver Found.
)


ECHO * Copying Files...
xcopy "%SOURCEPATH%\Documents" "%BACKPATH%\%BACKUP_DEST%\MPMissions" /v /e /s /i /y 1>NUL 2>NUL

ECHO * Archiving files...
CD /D "%BACKPATH%"
FOR /f %%a IN ('FORFILES /P %BACKPATH% /C "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE echo @file" /D -%DAYSTOKEEP%') DO (
IF NOT EXIST %%a.7z (
    "%ARCPATH%" %ARCPARAMS% %%a.7z %BACKPATH%\%%a\*.* 1>NUL 2>NUL
    copy %%a.7z %DEST_PATH% 1>NUL 2>NUL
    del %%a.7z 1>NUL 2>NUL
)
)

ECHO * Cleaning folders older than %DAYSTOKEEP% days..
FORFILES /P %BACKPATH% /C "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE rmdir /s /q @file" /D -%DAYSTOKEEP% 1>NUL 2>NUL

ECHO * Cleaning files older than %DAYSTOKEEP% days..
FORFILES /P %BACKPATH% /M *.7z /C "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE del @file" /D -%DAYSTOKEEP% 1>NUL 2>NUL

ECHO * Cleaning archives files older than %ARCHIVE_DAYSTOKEEP% days..
FORFILES /P %DEST_PATH% /M *.7z /C "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE del @file" /D -%ARCHIVE_DAYSTOKEEP% 1>NUL 2>NUL


:END
ENDLOCAL
```

once I run the script it gives this message:

- Setting up environment variables.
- Backup Path Found.
- Archiver Found.
- Copying Files...
- Archiving files...
  ERROR: No files found with the specified search criteria.
- Cleaning folders older than 3 days..
- Cleaning files older than 3 days..
- Cleaning archives files older than 30 days..
  The script has executed successfully. You may close this window.

Now the variable %ThisService_RootDirectory% is part of tcadmin which is a gaming server service, so that variable where im executing the batch script would turn that variable into an actual path of the users service
example:
%ThisService_RootDirectory%
is 
C:\TCAFiles\users\admin\5\

the script copies the files to the required folder, but it does not seem to zip the files and move the zip to the required folder.

can anyone give some assistance here please.

original source is at https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/482860-batch-script-to-transfer-and-compress

Answer (score 1):

It's not a direct response to your question but why reinvent the wheel ?
All you need is in [7zBackup.ps1](http://7zBackup.codeplex.com) (a powershell script which does exactly this)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I looked into this already. Unfortunately it will not work for my application. I need it so my main script can add variables based on the user executing it.  It cannot be a multifile script and my only options to execute the script are iron python and batch/shell script.